# Firebase Functions 1.0.0 migration: Trouble with custom initializeApp() with Google Service Account credential

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I just updated from the beta (v0.9.1) to v1.0.0, and ran into some problems with initialization. As per the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase_admin), `functions.config().firebase` is now deprecated. Here is my initialization before:

```
const serviceAccount = require('../service-account.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: functions.config().firebase.databaseURL,
  storageBucket: functions.config().firebase.storageBucket,
  projectId: functions.config().firebase.projectId,
})
```

Here is what I changed it to after upgrading:

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

At first this seems to work fine, the databaseURL and storageBucket are being recognized. However, there is a problem regarding the newly absent `credential` field. That field is required in order to access Google Cloud Storage. I access the `@google-cloud/storage` API in my app like so:

```
import { Bucket, File } from '@google-cloud/storage'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

bucket: Bucket = admin.storage().bucket()

    this.bucket
      .upload(filepath, {
        destination: uploadPath,
      })
      .then((fileTuple: [File]) => {
        // after uploading, save a reference to the audio file in the DB
        fileTuple[0]
          .getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-17-2025' })
          .then((url: [string]) => {
            dbRef.child('audioFiles').push(url[0])
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err))

        console.log(`${filepath} uploaded to ${this.bucket.name}.`)
      })
```

This uploads a file to storage, then it inserts the signed URL into my Realtime Database.

After migration, this chunk of code gives the following error:

```
SigningError: Cannot sign data without `client_email`
```

Since `client_email` was a field on `service-account.json`, I suspect that I need to reinsert `credentials`, like so:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
})
```

When I try this, however, I get errors like `Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.` or `Error: Bucket name not specified or invalid.`. So if I manually insert `credential`, it appears to expect `databaseURL` and `storageBucket` to be manually inserted as well.

So the question is, how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I had to rewrite my init call like this:

```
const serviceAccount = require('../service-account.json')
const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL,
  storageBucket: firebaseConfig.storageBucket,
  projectId: firebaseConfig.projectId,
})
```