# Trying to upload to firebase storage through a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a zip file that is created in a firebase cloud function to firebase storage. I have my code setup as follows:

```
const appConfig = {
  credential: admin.credential.cert(ServiceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
};
const app = admin.initializeApp(appConfig);
export const db = app.firestore();
export const auth = app.auth();
export const storage = app.storage().bucket();
```

I then import storage into my function and run the following:

```
const options = {
    gzip: true,
    uploadType: 'media',
    destination: `${filename}.zip`,
    metadata: {
      metadata,
      contentType: 'application/zip',
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
  };

  const storageData = await storage.upload(file, options)
    .catch((error) => {
      throwError('unknown', 'Error uploading exported data to store', error);
    });
```

when trying to upload the file, I receive the following error.

```
error: { Error: Cannot parse JSON response
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:167:42)
    at Util.handleResp (functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:116:117)
    at retryRequest (functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:404:22)
    at onResponse (functions/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
    at functions/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:158:17
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) message: 'Cannot parse JSON response' }
```

It appears that `Util.parseHttpRespBody` is receiving a body of "Not Found". I've seen similar questions but they all seem to be related to the bucket name. I'm using the default bucket and am a bit lost. What am I missing? Why is the body of the call to storage set as "Not Found"?

Comment: If you're using default everything, do you even need to pass a config argument to `initailizeApp()`?  When running in Cloud Functions and other Google environments, the environment is already configured to give you sensible defaults for your project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do. I am accessing another project within this function and if I don't define each, I can't access the "external" one. But that looks like it is the problem, if I remove the initialization, it works fine.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson. if you can submit this as the answer, I can mark it as correct as it looks like this is the root of the issue. I will have to open a new question related to the two projects question. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really a solution to your problem.  You should be able to reach into storage buckets from other projects, as long as the service account has access to do so.  There's just not enough information to know what's gone wrong.

Comment: you are correct. It did lead me to the correct solution. Appreciate your time on this one. The configuration let me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697107/firebase-functions-1-0-0-migration-trouble-with-custom-initializeapp-with-goo which allowed me to initialize both projects without a problem and everything is working as intended now.